# Does zoom's "Join from Your Browser" work with their "Call me" feature?

Tags: audio, zoom.us

Somebody has suggested to me to use the zoom "Call me" feature (which isn't available unless you're calling into a meeting with somebody with a paid account who has "Call me" enabled).

I've always used only "Join from Your Browser", i.e. the web app version of zoom, not the app.  However, though the [call me support page](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/200942859-Joining-meeting-audio-by-phone-call-me-) does not list the app as a requirement (and neither does [this page about enabling "call me"](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360060596392-Enabling-or-disabling-call-me-and-invite-by-phone)), the similar feature "Dial in" doesn't seem to be present in the web app version.  Does "Call me" work with the web app?

Comment: Please checkout https://support.zoom.us . I closed this question because it doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). Related:  [As a mod when should I vote to close content that is not flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124097/289691)